# Some problems with android listview

Tags: android, listview

I am trying to make some practice about android `ListView`. Code bellow is in a
`listfragment`:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        View view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.frag_getfriends,container,false);
         friendsListView=(ListView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.list);

        infoTextView=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.empty);
        swipe=(SwipeRefreshLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
        swipe.setOnRefreshListener(this);
        arrayAdapter=new DataListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.userinfo_list_config,null);
        friendsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        friendsListView.setOnItemClickListener((parent,itemView,position,id)->{
            if(friends!=null){
                     User friend=friends.get(position);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),friend.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

       presenter.startQuery(true);
        return view;
    }
```

`Adapter` constructor is:

```
 public DataListAdapter(Context context, int itemLayoutResoureId, ArrayList<User>friends){
        super(context,itemLayoutResoureId,friends);
        this.context=context;
        this.users=new ArrayList<>();
        users.addAll(friends);
    }
```

At the beginning,the `listview` has no data to display until this app fetches some data online:

```
@Override
    public void setDataList(ArrayList<User> friendsList) {
        this.friends=friendsList;
        arrayAdapter.clear();
        arrayAdapter.addAll(friendsList);
        arrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        friendsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);

    }
```

Later I can do some refresh.And each refresh happenes,the callback

```
setDataList
```

is fired and `listview` get updated.
However,the app crashed.  Logcat shows:

```
 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.mrdreamer.iknow/com.example.mrdreamer.iknow.Social.GetFriends}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2416)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344)
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                                            Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'java.lang.Object[] java.util.Collection.toArray()' on a null object reference
                                                                               at java.util.ArrayList.addAll(ArrayList.java:188)
                                                                               at com.example.mrdreamer.iknow.Social.DataListAdapter.<init>(DataListAdapter.java:35)
                                                                               at com.example.mrdreamer.iknow.Social.GetFriendsFrag.onCreateView(GetFriendsFrag.java:42)
                                                                               at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2220)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:973)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1148)
                                                                               at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:793)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1535)
                                                                               at android.app.FragmentController.execPendingActions(FragmentController.java:325)
                                                                               at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:6252)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2379)
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2476) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1344) 
                                                                               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417) 
                                                                               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726) 
                                                                               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

The problem is that in:

```
arrayAdapter=new DataListAdapter(getActivity(),R.layout.userinfo_list_config,null);
```

the last parameter cannot be null,which I understand.
Now should I change  to SimpleCursorAdapter or just make some change to current code? :) Thank you in advance.I am new to android developement.I am be very gratefull.:)

Comment: upload your crash log

Comment: @吴环宇,   post ur Adapter class constructor

Comment: Use CustomArrayAdapter. Google it.

Answer (score 0):

you can try like dis `/********* Adapter class extends with BaseAdapter and implements with OnClickListener ************/
public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter   implements OnClickListener {

```
     /*********** Declare Used Variables *********/
     private Activity activity;
     private ArrayList data;
     private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
     public Resources res;
     ListModel tempValues=null;
     int i=0;

     /*************  CustomAdapter Constructor *****************/
     public CustomAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList d,Resources resLocal) {

            /********** Take passed values **********/
             activity = a;
             data=d;
             res = resLocal;

             /***********  Layout inflator to call external xml layout () ***********/
              inflater = ( LayoutInflater )activity.
                                          getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

     }

     /******** What is the size of Passed Arraylist Size ************/
     public int getCount() {

         if(data.size()<=0)
             return 1;
         return data.size();
     }

     public Object getItem(int position) {
         return position;
     }

     public long getItemId(int position) {
         return position;
     }

     /********* Create a holder Class to contain inflated xml file elements *********/
     public static class ViewHolder{

         public TextView text;
         public TextView text1;
         public TextView textWide;
         public ImageView image;

     }

     /****** Depends upon data size called for each row , Create each ListView row *****/
     public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         View vi = convertView;
         ViewHolder holder;

         if(convertView==null){

             /****** Inflate tabitem.xml file for each row ( Defined below ) *******/
             vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabitem, null);

             /****** View Holder Object to contain tabitem.xml file elements ******/

             holder = new ViewHolder();
             holder.text = (TextView) vi.findViewById(R.id.text);
             holder.text1=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text1);
             holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);

            /************  Set holder with LayoutInflater ************/
             vi.setTag( holder );
         }
         else 
             holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();

         if(data.size()<=0)
         {
             holder.text.setText("No Data");

         }
         else
         {
             /***** Get each Model object from Arraylist ********/
             tempValues=null;
             tempValues = ( ListModel ) data.get( position );

             /************  Set Model values in Holder elements ***********/

              holder.text.setText( tempValues.getCompanyName() );
              holder.text1.setText( tempValues.getUrl() );
               holder.image.setImageResource(
                           res.getIdentifier(
                           "com.androidexample.customlistview:drawable/"+tempValues.getImage()
                           ,null,null));

              /******** Set Item Click Listner for LayoutInflater for each row *******/

              vi.setOnClickListener(new OnItemClickListener( position ));
         }
         return vi;
     }

     @Override
     public void onClick(View v) {
             Log.v("CustomAdapter", "=====Row button clicked=====");
     }

     /********* Called when Item click in ListView ************/
     private class OnItemClickListener  implements OnClickListener{           
         private int mPosition;

         OnItemClickListener(int position){
              mPosition = position;
         }

         @Override
         public void onClick(View arg0) {


           CustomListViewAndroidExample sct = (CustomListViewAndroidExample)activity;

          /****  Call  onItemClick Method inside CustomListViewAndroidExample Class ( See Below )****/

             sct.onItemClick(mPosition);
         }               
     }   
 }`
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to use friendsListView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter); again in setDataList because you have already set adapter on listview. You have called notifydatasetchange. It is sufficent to update adapter with new items.